# Active and navbutton has weird padding with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to figure out how to use nav buttons with bootstrap, at the moment they look a little bit out of place if they're beside the `<li class="active">` the margins are wrong.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hjortefjellet</a>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li> <p class="navbar-btn"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">TTT</a></p></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Hjem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Doner</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakt oss</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Om oss</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Hjem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Doner</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

**[Bootjson](http://www.bootply.com/3i5XvHh2RH)**

I think you understand that I want the margins to be the same over all pages, so changing the margin of the navbar button won't be that good.

Comment: Please explain what's "wrong" about the margins. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

[image]

```
.navbar-btn {
margin-right: 8px;
}
```

More specific:

```
ul.nav p.navbar-btn {
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

You probably need to add a margin to the right of the button, as the li is next to it. But you don't see it unless it's active - because of the background color it gets when it's active.

There are other solutions, but in the end you need to either get some more space between them at all times, or only when the menu item is active - which looks awkward.

(Godt å se at det er noen norske innom her)